# Two arguments Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use two arguments in a function, but it's not working?
This is not the final function, I'm just trying to get the arguments to work.

the html:

```
<div id = "textButton" class = "convertButtonss" onclick = illegal_chr("bin" ,"binary")>
    <p id = "textButton_p">
        txt/dec
    </p>
</div>
```

the Javascript:

```
function illegal_chr(name, type) {
    alert(name);
    alert(type);
}
```

when I click on the div nothing happpens?

Comment: watch your whitespace too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping the entire attribute value in double quotes, and the string literals in single quotes, or vice versa, like this:

```
<div … onclick="illegal_chr('bin','binary')">
```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Remember that tag attributes in HTML must be surrounded by quotes or double-quotes.</strike> Try this:

```
<div id = "textButton" class = "convertButtonss" onclick = 'illegal_chr("bin" ,"binary")'>
    <p id = "textButton_p">
        txt/dec
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: attribs need not be quoted unless they have an "=" or " " in them, which this one does but need not to. You also can't have a space after the = of the attrib itself, even if you use quotes further to the right...

Comment: Mmm... Been conforming to XHTML for too long. Thanks!

Comment: break off those 1999 shackles and run free!

Comment: @dandavis—the list of characters in attribute values that [must be escaped](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/introduction.html#a-quick-introduction-to-html) is `" ' \` = < >.`.

Comment: @dandavis—yes, I mis–typed,  "escaped" should be "quoted". :-/